# What is the effect of a path separator at the beginning of an environment variable?

Tags: environment-variables

I was reading [a document](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2017/02/21/set-environment-variable-save-thousands-of-system-calls/) recommending setting the `TZ` variable in order to avoid unnecessary `stat` system calls in programs using `localtime`, and it uses the following syntax:

```
TZ=:/etc/localtime
```

The trick described in the document works, but it also works without the colon: `TZ=/etc/localtime`.

What might be the purpose of the `:` here?

Comment: No, this doesn't have anything to do with the default value in parameter expansion (that would need the `${...}`). `TZ=:/etc/localtime` just assigns a string with a literal colon.

Comment: Sorry! I completely missed the absence of `-`. My bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out this is a special thing for the `TZ` variable. The behavior is documented in [`man tzset`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/tzset) (emphasis mine):

> The second format specifies that the timezone information should be read from a file:
>
> ```
> :[filespec]
> ```
>
> If the file specification filespec is omitted, or its value cannot be interpreted, then Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) is used.   If  filespec
>   is  given,  it  specifies  another tzfile(5)-format file to read the timezone information from.  If filespec does not begin with a '/', the file specification is relative to the system timezone directory.  **If the colon is omitted each of the above TZ formats will be tried.**
>
> Here's an example, once more for New Zealand:
>
> ```
> TZ=":Pacific/Auckland"
> ```

If I understand the above correctly, both `TZ=:/etc/localtime` and `TZ=/etc/localtime` work as you said, but when the `:` is omitted, the system will try to parse what you give it as any of the various formats it accepts. I *think* that includes actual time definitions (see further up in the same man page).

So, using the `:` is a way of telling `tzset` not to bother to interpret what you give it but instead to treat it directly as a file.